# Converting JSON properties to numbers when serializing using Json.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

I want to output the following example data in JSON:

{"source_id":"1234","contacts":["15":"020 8111 1111"]}

I've tried using the following code to achieve this using Json.net:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Test.Utility
{
    public class RequestHelper
    {
        internal static string CreateData(string sourceId, string telephone)
        {
            JArray createContact = new ContactFieldHelper
            {
                Phone = new JValue(telephone)
            };

            var createData = new DataFieldHelper
            {
                SourceId = sourceId,
                CreateContact = createContact
            };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createData);
            return output;
        }

    }

    class DataFieldHelper
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "source_id")]
        public string SourceId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contacts")]
        public JArray CreateContact { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactFieldHelper : JArray
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "15")]
        public JValue Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, this is displaying a blank output for the "contacts" field. It works if only values are used but not when there are key value pairs in the JArray. So for instance the following will output:

{"source_id":"1234","contacts":["020 8111 1111"]}

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Test.Utility
{
    public class RequestHelper
    {
        internal static string CreateData(string sourceId, string telephone)
        {
            JArray createContact = new JArray
                                    {
                                        new JValue(telephone)
                                    };

            var createData = new DataFieldHelper
            {
                SourceId = sourceId,
                CreateContact = createContact
            };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createData);
            return output;
        }

    }

    class DataFieldHelper
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "source_id")]
        public string SourceId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contacts")]
        public JArray CreateContact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Simple metod to achive your goal at my personal advice is this :

Create your json string(take care to each parameters, array , name etc) (take a look here for [json examples](http://json.org/example.html) and take a look here to validate your json(which are invalid as it is wwrite) [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Go here http://json2csharp.com/ and convert your json in simple class with this tool

Import your new classes into your project and then serialize and deserialize in few rows with the class System.Web.Script.Serialization.Javascriptserializer

It will more simple and fast.

In example from your code:

```
{"source_id":"1234","contacts":["15":"020 8111 1111"]}(invalid json it gives error on validation )
```

Class derived :

```
 public class Contact
{
   public string __invalid_name__15 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public string source_id { get; set; }
  public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

if you want you can adorn your property or the entire class with serializable attribute then 
simply use javascriptserializar like here

```
protected void SerializeItem(string s){

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

RootObject rt = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(s);//deserialization from string to object
 string S = js.Serialize(RootObject);//serialization from object to complex json string

}
```

To more clean i changed a little bit your json code adn here derived class

```
public class Contact
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string phone { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
{
public string sourceid { get; set; }
public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

here json revisited for example:

```
    {"sourceid": "1234",
        "contacts": [
                      {
                        "id": "15",
                        "phone":"020 8111 1111"
                       }
                     ]
     }
```